# escape special character in xml

Tags: java, xml, escaping, special-characters

I run this query in the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    ..
    ...
    <query> 
         update tableX set colName='$ClassService.getParameter(\"param1\")$' where id = '0'
    </query>
    ...
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR]: Exception occurred, terminating.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception parsing or evaluating
>   ClassService.getParameter(\"param1\")

How to escape " correctly?

Comment: There not need to escape `"` characters in XML unless you find them in attributes. I think you can write directly `ClassService.getParameter("param1")`

Comment: Well I got the same error

Comment: So I guess you problem doesn't lie in XML escaping. Your XML is evaluated and used elsewhere, and raises the exception. Perhaps you can send the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

What about just use a CDATA-section for this?

```
 <![CDATA[
 Within this Character Data block I can
 use double dashes as much as I want (along with <, &, ', and ")
 *and* %MyParamEntity; will be expanded to the text
 "Has been expanded" ... however, I can't use
 the CEND sequence (if I need to use it I must escape one of the
 brackets or the greater-than sign).
 ]]>
```

Or does this not fit your requirement?

So that it will look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
..
...
<query> 
     <![CDATA[
     update tableX set colName='$ClassService.getParameter(\"param1\")$' where id = '0'
     ]]>
</query>
...
```